# R Error in context_eval(join(src), private$context) : v8::Context has been disposed

Tags: r, v8

I'm trying to use a function built into the Global Environment, but I keep getting this error from the v8 package. How can I work around it?

```
Error in context_eval(join(src), private$context) : 
  v8::Context has been disposed.
```